# Integrating area under a PDF distribution curve

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have plotted the PDF of a particular function using

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[64, 8.5333333], x], {x, 20, 100}]
```

This gives the curve

[image: Distribution of 8000 data points]

I want to find the probability of finding a data point in a particular region of this graph by integrating the area under the curve. I want to do this for a small section of the graph only, i.e. for a small range of values of $A_i$. How do I go about this?

Comment: Try `Quantile`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what `CDF` is good for!

```
f = PDF[NormalDistribution[64, 8.5333333]];
F = CDF[NormalDistribution[64, 8.5333333]];
F[b] - F[a]
```

returns the area of the graph of `f` between the points `a` and `b`.

Comment: So if I want to find how many of my 8000 data points are in a region I just do (F[b]-F[a])*8000?

Comment: Yepp...........

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CDF` function, e.g.

```
(* 5% one-tail probability *)
x = Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 0.05]
```

> -1.64485

```
Show[Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], a], {a, -4, 4},
  Ticks -> {{{-4, "μ - 4σ"}, {-2, "μ - 2σ"},
     {2, "μ + 2σ"}, {4, "μ + 4σ"}}, None}],
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], b], {b, -4, x},
  PlotStyle -> None, Filling -> Axis]]
```

[image]

```
CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]
```

> 0.05

`CDF` returns 5%.